# Proof that $\log_{10} 2$ is irrational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, real-numbers

I am student of high school and have a question from my math book.

**Q. Prove that $\log 2$ is irrational.**

I had a proof using contradiction as follows
Let

$$\log 2=\frac{p}{q}$$

$$10^\frac{p}{q} = 2$$

$$10^p = 2^q$$

$$(2 \times 5)^p = 2^q$$

$$5^p = 2^{q-p}$$

Now since a power of 2 can never be equal to power of 5 it leads to a contradiction and hence the assumption is false.

This proof is okay, but I was thinking of any other proof of it which could make me more comfortable than that proof.
So I only request a rigorous proof of irrationality of $\log 2$, using simple high school math or else using calculus and other stuff(I don't mind the way you use to solve the problem but interested in alternative proof of the irrationality of $\log 2$.

Comment: Log2 refers to general logarithm and not the natural logarithm.

Comment: $2^0=5^0$, so you should explain why $p$ and $q-p$ are not both $0$

Comment: can you say what about your proof makes you uncomfortable?

Comment: That is the easiest proof for it's irrationality. Any other proof would I suppose use some overkill machinery.

Comment: Since you tag your question as number theory, you probably know about the uniqueness theorem for prime factorization of integers. That's all you need to add to the proof, in order to make it 100% rigorous.

Comment: @Rahul: What does "general logarithm" mean? Do you mean the so-called "common logarithm", base 10?

Comment: Why aren't you comfortable with that proof?  I don't think we can come up with anything to make you more comfortable if we don't know what makes you uncomfortable.

Comment: By comfortable I mean much rigorous proof than this. And by general logarithm I meant by common logarithm i.e base 10. In simple words I request any other proof than this contradiction. Kaind, I never mind with the complexity of proof but just needed a proof apart from that. Hope you understand me.

Comment: @Rahul I think you are underestimating the kind of machinery people will bring to find an alternate solution. If you are having trouble in 'rigorizing' that proof, I'm quite certain the alternate proofs will employ theorems you've never heard of.

Comment: I believe your 'dilemma' lies in solving this subproblem:
Prove formally that if $p_1$ and $p_2$ are distinct primes, and $a$ and $b$ are integers, then $p_1^a = p_2^b \Rightarrow a = b = 0$.

Comment: What lacks "rigor" in this proof?

Comment: This is the perfect proof. There is nothing missing (except that you have to dismiss the case $p=q-p=0$). We are all baffled by your reluctance to accept it.

Comment: I'm having a hard time with your issue of the proof. "Rational" means can written as a ratio of integers and if so it *does* follow completely that $5^p = 2^{q-p}$ and $p$ and $q-p$ are integers. It makes the claim that powers of 2 cant be a power of 5 and for positive integers that is just the fundamental theorem prime factorizations.  It seems to assume $p$ and $q-p$ are positve but that is *easily* addressed.  So ... where's the lack of rigor. *WHY* don't you like the proof?  We can't answer you question unless we know *WHY* you don't like the proof.

Answer (score 1):

If $\log_{10}(2)$ is rational, there must be two naturals $n,m$ such that

$$n\log_{10}(2)=m.$$

Taking the antilogarithm,

$$2^n=10^m.$$

But no power of $2$ ends in $0$ !

Comment: Exactly Yves Daoust, I need a proof that no power of 2 ends with 0. I mean I demand a proof of everything we state.( I agree that what I am asking is quite ridiculous but I want a proof of everything we state)

Comment: @Rahul: this is elementary by induction. Your task.

Comment: Ya realized the same thing. Thank you.

Comment: @lonestudent: then explain me what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so $\log 2$ is the $x$ so that $10^x = 2$

Therefore $\frac {10^x}2 =1$

So $2^{x-1}5^{x} = 1$

Let's assume $x$ is rational and can be written as a fraction $\frac pq$.

If $x=\frac pq$ then $x -1 = \frac pq - 1= \frac pq -\frac qq = \frac {p-q}q$.

So $2^{\frac {p-q}q}5^{\frac pq} = 1$

So $2^{p-q} 5^p = 1^q = 1$

So $5^p = \frac 1{2^{p-q}}= 2^{q-p}$

If $q>p$ then $q-p > 0$ and $2^{q-p}$ is an integer and a positive integer power of $2$ and greater than $1$ ans $5^p > 1$ and $p$ is a positive power integer of $5$. But a power of $2$ only has $2$ as a prime factor and a power of $5$ only has $5$ as prime factors.  SO this is impossible.

If $q < p$ then $q-p < 0$ and $2^{q-p}= \frac 1{2^{p-q}}$ is a reciprocal of an integer.  So $5^p$ is not an integer and $p$ must be negative. So $5^p = \frac 1{5^{|p|}}$ and $2^{q-p} = \frac 1{2^{|q-p|}}$ so $5^{|p|} = 2^{|q-p|}$. And this is the same case as the paragraph above and impossible as powers of $2$ have only $2$ as prime factors and powers or $5$ only have $5$.

And if $q = p$ then $\frac pq = x = 1$.  That would mean $\log 2 = 1$.  That would mean $10^1 = 2$ or $10 =2$. That isn't true.

None of the options are possible so $\log 2$ is either irrational or simply does not exist.....

Which, I guess, means we have to prove there *does* exist a real number so that $10^x =2$....  That may have been a basic assumption.  The usually idea is that $10^0 =1 < 2$ and $10^1 > 2$ and $10^{\frac 12} \approx 3.16 > 2$ and if we take it as a general assumption about real numbers and $10^x$ that it doesn't "jump about" there has to be *some* number in there where $10^x = 2$.  I think that was a basic assumption in the question that $\log 2$ actually exists.

.....

Now this proof is *exactly* the same as the one you gave.  But maybe I put int in terms from concepts that do follow one after one and a way that follows one's natural thought process.

IMO I prefer the proof as given.  But they are the same.